# Task Scheduler is not working even though its running

Tags: batch-file, xampp, scheduled-tasks, windows-10

I have windows 10 installed. I have created a bat file to run my php scripts.

I tested the bat file in the cmd and it works fine(The php script was to delete non-activated users).

bat file:

```
"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" -f C:\xampp\htdocs\cron_jobs\once_daily.php
```

php file:

```
<?php
include("../cust/mysql_connect.php");
$mysqli = db_connect();
$sql = "DELETE FROM customer WHERE  Activate=0";

error_log("You messed up!", 3, "my-errors.log");

if (!$mysqli->query($sql))
  {
      die ('Error : ' . mysqli_error());
  }
?>
```

But when I use the task scheduler, it just runs and does nothing. It did not delete anything, I have just recently started using the task scheduler.

**

### UPDATED

**

**Create Task:**
This is where I set name and highest privileges as admin.

[image: This is where I set name and highest privileges ad admin]

**Set Action:**
I set the .bat file location and the **Trigger** tab is empty as I didn't need to use a trigger for this event.

[image]

**Conditions left as default:**
I didn't change this but to show.

[image]

**Setting left as default:**
I didn't change this but to show.

[image]

**Shown as running:**
Overview the task created and running.

[image]

**PhpMyAdmin:**
It did not delete the row with Activate = 0.

[image]

**History of the task scheduler event:**
It seems to run but does nothing in my case.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the task Author have administrator privilegies?

Comment: Well I did ran the task scheduler as administrator when I opened it

Comment: Yes, and what about the Author? Is it in Administrators group? ([See here](http://imgur.com/CyTlRMz))

Comment: User, Group, or Built-in security principal are all ticked. Also run as high privilege. still nothing working

Comment: I only added an action but did not added a trigger, perhaps this is a problem?

Comment: nvm it does not work.

Comment: Did you debug it? See if the script is *actually* running smooth by the task scheduler (set the php script to record a log in the end, with error outputs etc) to be sure it only *does nothing* or it's being stopped by something.

Comment: When I clicked run, it says running as image above. I am sure the php script has 0 errors because the scheduler is not even running it, it wont do any error logs.

Comment: You're showing very little of the configuration for the task scheduler, so it's hard to tell what you're even doing.  Looking at your PHP script (which looks cut off since it's missing the `<?php`) it looks like all it does is `error_log("You messed up!", 3, "my-errors.log");`.  Everything else is pointless flow control with undefined variables or commented out.  Have you searched for `C:\Windows\my-error.log` or `C:\Windows\System32\my-error.log`?  Task scheduler starts a session with one of those as the current path, you never specify the path anywhere.

Comment: I couldn't find this my-error.log  you mention through search. But there is history of the tasks.

Comment: I have updated everything I know of..

Comment: I just downloaded z-cron and it worked fine, so to conclude..task scheduler may not have worked with windows 10 or I am missing files.